# Issues rendering videos on Edge

Tags: html, video, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I've crawled every corner of the web that I know of and cannot understand why videos are struggling to render on MS Edge.

I cannot paste the exact code as it's a project in work but it follows the format of

```
<video>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<video>
```

and to complicate things further, it displays correctly on Edge with some colleagues but not with others. Initially thought it could be a version of Edge that didn't support the codecs which would be strange as it was the newer versions of Edge (V42.17134.1.0) that was failing in work to display the video correctly but older versions were fine. However, when I got home I asked friends to check their versions and if it worked for them and people are reporting that everything works fine with them on V42.17134.1.0.

So that lead me to the question of, could it be hardware/software? So I've just checked for updates and installed everything to absolutely no change. The video still doesn't display.

Using [www.youtube.com/html5](https://www.youtube.com/html5) I can see that on my machine nothing is supported on Edge with HTMLVideoElement throwing up an exclamation mark. Whereas my friend who is on the exact identical version of Edge as me has full support based on this url.

Any advice, tips would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your code and with that YouTube URL. Looks like everything is fine on my side.

[image]

[image]

Maybe, There is some issue on your end. I suggest you to first try to repair your Edge application, If issue persist than try to reset the Edge application may help to solve this issue.

To Repair or Reset the Edge, You can refer steps below.

(1) Go to Settings in your windows 10 OS.

(2) Click on Apps.

(3) Search for MS Edge in Apps & features.

[image]

(4) Click on Advanced options.

(5) Scroll down and find Reset or Repair option.

[image]

(6) Perform the Repair or Reset by clicking on the button.